# Pandas mask with boolean operation: ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am writing a quick and dirty data sanitation script and I need to check that the data columns have the correct relative ranking.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
dt                        op     hi      lo        cl        vol           adj       prev                                                        
1986-01-02  1986-01-02  177.00  177.00  177.0000  177.00   75.8732         0.0         NaN
1986-01-03  1986-01-03  176.00  176.00  176.0000  176.00   75.4447         0.0  1986-01-02
1986-01-06  1986-01-06  172.00  172.00  172.0000  172.00   73.7299         0.0  1986-01-03
1986-01-07  1986-01-07  167.00  167.00  167.0000  167.00   71.5868         0.0  1986-01-06
1986-01-09  1986-01-09  168.00  168.00  168.0000  168.00   72.0153         0.0  1986-01-07
...                ...     ...     ...       ...     ...       ...         ...         ...
2020-09-14  2020-09-14  102.20  105.60  101.6500  104.70  104.7000   9720916.0  2020-09-11
2020-09-15  2020-09-15  106.45  110.70  106.4500  109.25  109.2500  15923105.0  2020-09-14
2020-09-16  2020-09-16  107.95  112.55  107.9500  112.10  112.1000  15399144.0  2020-09-15
2020-09-17  2020-09-17  110.40  112.85  110.0500  112.00  112.0000   6737225.0  2020-09-16
2020-09-18  2020-09-18  111.50  111.75  109.3923  110.75  110.7500  25308704.0  2020-09-17
```

I want to create a mask like this:

`mask = df[(df.hi >= df.op) & (df.hi >= df.lo) & (df.hi >= df.cl) & (df.lo <= df.op) & (df.lo <= df.cl)]`

However, when I try to select from df using `df[mask`], I get the error message:

> ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object

This is what I want to do:

1. Set boolean flag which is the result of the test above
2. Convert boolean to int (0,1)
3. Sum the column of the ints to see if it is a non zero number

How do I set the flag in a column in the dataframe based on my test condition?

Comment: arent you already creating the data that you need since you have `df` before all those conditions?

Comment: you are doing `dataset[dataset]`

Comment: `df[df]` `ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only` 
I might be wrong but thats what i see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mask should be:

```
mask = (df.hi >= df.op) & (df.hi >= df.lo) & (df.hi >= df.cl) & (df.lo <= df.op) & (df.lo <= df.cl)
```

Insert that into the df with `df[mask]`